# android application that is visible on lock screen same as emergency calls button

Tags: android

How to create an android app that will appear on the lock screen and can be started even if the phone is lock?

Such that the application icon is visible on the lock screen instead of menu.  Similar to emergency calls button on the lock screen.

Can anyone please help me out in this?

I read many things but was not able to find such thing please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Android 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-lockscreen-widgets), you can create [lockscreen widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen). If the user places it on the lockscreen, it works mostly like any other widget.